# How close can we get to a cross product in dimensions other than $0, 1, 3, 7$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds, cross-product

A [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) is a bilinear operation which, given two input vectors $x, y$, produces a vector $x \times y$ orthogonal to both, whose length equals the area of the parallelogram spanned by $x$ and $y$.

The components of a cross product can be expressed using [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) as $(x\times y)_i = X_{ijk} x_j y_k$, where $X_{ijk}$ is a rank-3 totally antisymmetric tensor satisfying the following area condition:

$$X_{ijm} X_{mkl} + X_{jkm} X_{mli} = 2 \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}-\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}-\delta_{il}\delta_{kj},$$

where $\delta_{ij}$ denotes the Kronecker delta.

It is a [known fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product) that cross products only exist in dimensions $0, 1, 3$ and $7$. My question is essentially how close can a given totally antisymmetric tensor get to a cross product in dimensions other than these. One way to measure for some $X_{ijk}$ the failure to satisfy the area condition above is to set

$$\Delta_{ijkl} = (X_{ijm} X_{mkl} + X_{jkm} X_{mli}) - (2 \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}-\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}-\delta_{il}\delta_{kj}),$$

and define the scalar $\Delta = \Delta_{ijkl} \Delta_{ijkl}$. In practical terms, $\Delta$ can be thought of as the average value of the squared deviation $(|x\times y|^2-\operatorname{area}(x,y)^2)^2$ over all unit vectors $x, y \in S^{n-1}$, where $\times$ is the bilinear product associated to $X_{ijk}$.

Note that if $X_{ijk}$ defines a true cross product, we clearly have $\Delta(X_{ijk}) = 0$; otherwise, $\Delta(X_{ijk})$ will take some positive value (since it is a sum of squares). We now define the minimum average deviation $\Delta_{\mathrm{min}}$ by minimizing $\Delta$ over all possible rank-3 totally antisymmetric tensors, i.e.,

$$\Delta_{\mathrm{min}} = \min_{X_{ijk} \in \Lambda^3\mathbb{R}^n} \Delta(X_{ijk}).$$

This quantity only depends on the dimension $n$. Here is a table with some values I've computed in Mathematica (unfortunately the computations take more than half an hour to complete after $n=12$. I can provide my code if needed):

| $n$ | $0$ | $1$ | $2$ | $3$ | $4$ | $5$ | $6$ | $7$ | $8$ | $9$ | $10$ | $11$ | $12$ | $13$ | $14$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\Delta_{\mathrm{min}}(n)$ | $0$ | $0$ | $6$ | $0$ | $36$ | $\frac{672}{11}$ | $72$ | $0$ | $84$ | $\frac{351}{2}$ | $269.207$ | $326.737$ | $448.972$ | $528$ | $588$ |

Surprisingly, the values up to $n=9$ turn out to be rational numbers (to a very good approximation at least). However, for $n\ge 10$ this doesn't seem to necessarily hold anymore, so there probably isn't a nice formula for the minimum average deviation as a function of $n$. Instead of that, I would like to ask about its growth properties.

My questions are:

1. **Is there any (nontrivial) asymptotic lower bound for $\Delta_{\mathrm{min}}(n)$?**

Note that there is an obvious upper bound $\Delta_{\mathrm{min}}(n) \le 6n(n-1)$ obtained by setting $X_{ijk}$ to zero. Apparently the actual values tend to be close to half of that, that is, $\Delta_{\mathrm{min}}(n) \simeq 3n(n-1)$ seems to hold.

2. **Is $\Delta_{\mathrm{min}}(n)$ nondecreasing for all $n>7$? If not, what are the dimensions where it decreases?**

---

EDIT: Here is the Mathematica code I'm using:

```
n = 5; (* the dimension is specified here *)

xarray = 
 SymmetrizedArray[
  pos_ :> Subscript[x, StringJoin[ToString /@ pos]], {n, n, n}, 
  Antisymmetric[All]];
x2 = (Activate@
    TensorContract[
     Inactive[TensorProduct][xarray, xarray], {{1, 4}}])/2;
id2 = 2 Transpose[
   Symmetrize[TensorProduct[IdentityMatrix[n], IdentityMatrix[n]], 
    Antisymmetric[{1, 3}]], {1, 3, 2, 4}];
delta = Flatten[
  Flatten /@ (x2 - id2 + Transpose[x2 - id2, {2, 3, 4, 1}])];
deltan = N[DeleteCases[delta, 0]];

AbsoluteTiming[
 NMinimize[Total[Map[#^2 &, deltan]], Variables@Normal[xarray], 
   WorkingPrecision -> 4]]

(* output should be: { Computation time, { minimum Delta, X_ijk that achieves it } } *)
(* increasing WorkingPrecision gives more digits, but takes more time *)
```

EDIT 2: I managed to make it work for $n=13$ and $n=14$ by pre-simplifying the minimization function and leaving it running all night; I updated the table with these two new values. Interestingly, they are rational numbers again.

I don't have the $n=15$ case yet, but following the discussion in the comments I have computed $\Delta(X^{\mathbb{S}}_{ijk})$ for a single $15$-dimensional tensor $X^{\mathbb{S}}_{ijk}$ defined in the following way: if $a$ and $b$ are two purely imaginary [sedenions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedenion) and $\Im ab$ denotes the imaginary part of their multiplication, we have $(\Im ab)_i = X^{\mathbb{S}}_{ijk} a_j b_k$.

Since all previous Cayley-Dickson algebras (real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ and octonions $\mathbb{O}$) satisfy $\Delta(X^{\mathbb{R}}_{ijk})=\Delta(X^{\mathbb{C}}_{ijk})=\Delta(X^{\mathbb{H}}_{ijk})=\Delta(X^{\mathbb{O}}_{ijk})=0$, it is in principle reasonable to think that $\Delta(X^{\mathbb{S}}_{ijk})$ will also be relatively small, perhaps a local minimum. However, it turns out that

$$\Delta(X^{\mathbb{S}}_{ijk})=1152,$$

which almost saturates the bound $6\cdot15(15-1)=1260$. So contrary to my expectations, sedenions spectacularly fail to define anything close to a cross product. Even a simple rescaling $\Delta(0.5 X^{\mathbb{S}}_{ijk}) = 891$ does it better.

Comment: Try $n=15$ in your code, this should be a local min if not $0$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks for your comment. I also have a hunch that dimensions $n=2^k-1$ might be local minima, but unfortunately my code seemingly cannot handle values higher than $12$ (it gave an error after more than an hour of computation). I don't know how feasible it will be to numerically compute these values after some point, since the complexity of the minimization function grows very quickly as $n$ increases; in any case I've edited my question with the code.

Comment: It's more than a hunch, have you seen a construction of cross products before? Cross products always exist as the "imaginary" part of a normed division algebra, which only exist in $2^n$ dimensions. For example taking a vector to a (imaginary) quaternion $(a,b,c)\to ai+bj+ck$ and quaternion multiplying with another vector gives the negative dot product as the real part and the cross product as the imaginary part. Doing the same thing with octonians retrieves the 7 dimensional cross product.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes, I know about the construction and why it works for $n=0, 1, 3, 7$. The next steps ([sedenions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedenion) and above) are not division algebras because they contain zero divisors, so they do not produce cross products on their imaginary subspaces, but nevertheless it might be possible to construct a (nonzero) local minimum of $\Delta_{\mathrm{min}}$ using them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a notion of 'circulation', which applies to every dimension subset to another dimension.  This equates to if one imagines some kind of circulation in a closed loop, an equivalent circulation exists in the orthogonal.

For example, if one supposes that the faces (ie N-1 d) of a polytope has an out-vector that is normal to the surface, then the removal of a number of faces of that polytope will leave a 'ring' (ie surface N-2 without interior N-1), that has a net vector equal to the sum of vectors spanning the hole, and any alternate cover of this hole will have the same out-vector sum.  This is a generalisation of the magnetic dipole = current × vector-area.

Not all of these constitute an algebraic space, but it is evident that any open loop (of any dimension m), has a circulation that matches the space orthogonal to it (ie n-m), in such a way that the circulation or direction of space is transferred.

I believe this is something that Clifford may have looked at.  I am also looking at this identical matter from first principles.

Comment: I'm confused, did you mean to post this in another question? My question is about cross products.

Comment: No.  Cross products are a variation of circulation, which exists in every dimension.  The implementation exists in every dimension, in that the volume of a pallopeid is the determinate of column vectors, and one can suppose the dot product is against N-1 vectors to give the normal.